# Dojo dijit.layout.TabContainer - how to add class to tab?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout, digit

Ho to add class to the tab in TabContainer?

Only thing I've found is set iconClass. However I need to add class to the parent div in tab. Not to some nested divs inside it.

Comment: Show us what you done so far, so we can help you in better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a simple way, but I got access to the tab button in the tabcontainer object.

```
var tabContainer = ...; 
dojo.addClass(tabContainer.tablist.pane2button["123"].domNode, "myTabClass");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/N2hsG/

Answer (score 1):

Building on Craig's suggestion, here's the modern way of doing it:

```
// assuming there is only one tabContainer on the page it will have an id of 'tab_container'
require( [ 'dijit/registry', 'dojo/dom-class' ], 
    function( registry, domClass )
{
    domClass.add( registry.byId( 'tab_container' ).tablist.pane2button['my_pane_id'].domNode, 'my_css_class' );
} );
```