# Custom CSS Class for dijit/layout/ContentPane

Tags: css, dojo, tabcontainer, contentpane

I want to add a custom CSS Class to a dijit/layout/ContentPane so I'm able to style it myself.

This is cause I got more than one tab in my TabContainer where my ContentPanes are located and I don't want to double the borders. Using a border all around the Tab will double the border so I removed the left border of the tabs. In the first tab in the TabContainer I need the left border, too.

To get this I tried to assume the first ContentPane a custom CSS class which will do it.

As you see me writing here, I didn't find a way to do this.

I tried it within the data-dojo-props with

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="FunnyTitle" data-dojo-props="class:'firstTab'">
```

So this didn't work. I tried to add it like I do it in a simple HTML element with class="firstTab"

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="FunnyTitle" class="firstTab">
```

Both ways didn't add my class to the ContentPane.

So how is it done?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636360/dojo-dijit-layout-tabcontainer-how-to-add-class-to-tab ?

Comment: it's works for Dojo 1.7 I got 1.10 here so "pane2button" which is used there doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The `class` property is actually not used for that kind of purpose, but it used for identifying of which type the widget is.

However, the `class` attribute should work, because declarative widgets usually keep their parent attributes. If I have the following HTML:

It eventually gets rendered into:

```
<div class="dijitContentPane test" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="myContent" widgetid="myContent">
    Hello
</div>
```

However, please note that when using a `dijit/layout/ContentPane` inside a `dijit/layout/TabContainer` a lot of additional CSS is added, possibily overriding your own CSS.

For example, for overriding the background color of a tab inside a `dijit/layout/TabContainer`, I had to use the following CSS selector:

```
.dijitTabContainerTop-dijitContentPane.test2 {
    background-color: #D4D4D1;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcog9saj/

But also, be aware that the borders generated by the `TabContainer` are not applied to the `ContentPane` itself, but to an element with classname `.dijitTabContainerTop-container` (part of the `TabContainer` itself).

---

If this really doesn't work, then you can always access the `domNode` property of the widget you're trying to alter, for example:

```
require(["dijit/registry", "dojo/ready", "dojo/dom-class"], function(registry, ready, domClass) {
    ready(function() {
        domClass.add(registry
            .byId("myContentPane")
            .get("domNode"), "test2");
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I wasn't specific enough. Your example adds a class to the "Content". I want to add a class to the Tab itself which the TabContainer generates out of the ContentPane. Or if you look at my example I mean that thing where the text "FunnyTitle" will appear.

Answer (score 0):

It's that simple that I didn't get it.

All you need to do is adding an ID to the ContentPane.

Dojo generates a widgetID with it like "dijit_layout_TabContainer_0_tablist_myID"

If the TabContainer itself has an ID, it could be different. Just have a look at the generated code.

Now you're able to get it with dijit.byId.

At the end it looks something like:

```js
var tab = dijit.byId("dijit_layout_TabContainer_0_tablist_myID");
domClass.add(tab.domNode,"myClassName");
```

domClass is a part of dojo. For using it you just need to require it "dojo/dom-class"

Comment: I see that you're mixing both old and new Dojo API code. `domClass` is indeed Dojo 1.7+, but `dijit.byId()` should be replaced by loading the module `dijit/registry` and using `registry.byId()`.

Comment: yeah that's right. Thanks for your hint. Btw. my answer wasn't totaly correct. It causes errors if the ContentPane is inside a Dialog. So if this happens, you need to get the ContentPane an ID, too. Dojo will create another ID for the tabcontainer without a changeing number after the Dialog was closed.